# UITableViewCell rowHeight with UITableViewAutomaticDimension doesn't work with compute autoLayout

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have UITableViewCell with multiple components act as rows, consist of mix elements of UILabel, UIView and UIStackView inside UIView.

[image]

Each component inside the cell has height constraint. I want the height of the cell to be dynamic by setting the constant of the height constraint zero or 21 at runtime, depend or whether it has content to show.

```
// more codes like below    
if let mealPref = passenger.mealPref {
    mealPrefHeight.constant = 21
    let title = R.string.localizable.meal_request.localized()
    mealPrefLabel.text = "• \(title): \(mealPref)"
} else {
    mealPrefHeight.constant = 0
}
// more codes like above
```

It doesn't work.

I have similar [problem back then](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47919986/1137814), but I think it's different case. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28383220/1137814), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43576502/1137814) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18746929/1137814).

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you change `constant ` of a constraint at run time `AutomaticDimension` won't work. If you set constant = 21 then automatic dimension will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you added in `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44 // for assumption
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: I added UITableViewAutomaticDimension in heightForRow section. Will try to add your code.

Comment: This is the solution. I need to set both `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` and `tableView.rowHeight` as your answer. +1 and I accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks, Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

try removeing height contraint.

```
if let mealPref = passenger.mealPref {
   let title = R.string.localizable.meal_request.localized()
   mealPrefLabel.text = "• \(title): \(mealPref)"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the `UITableViewCell's` height in `UITableViewDelegate` method:

> optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt
>   indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat

**Example:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        return 126.0
    }
    else
    {
        return 90.0
    }
}
```

You can change the height according to your requirement. Here I just used the row number to make the height changes.

**Screenshot:**

[image]